# Zomato - Menu fetch API (/dailymenu)

Tags: zomato-api

When i use Zomato API to fetch Menu(/dailymenu), its always returning the below response.

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "status": "Bad Request",
  "message": "No Daily Menu Available"
}
```

Anyone had any luck with this?

I believe Zomato is not exposing Menu Data.

I was trying for the city of Dubai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daily menu is supported in Prague, Czech Republic *only* and not in any other city where Zomato is present.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Nice to know this. Any idea if this is coming to other cities as well? So you from Zomato right? You should be having some inside info. :)